# percentage of numbers in a range

Tags: awk, range, percentage

I have a file with a range of inputs varying from 0-100. I want to generate the percentage of numbers below a range of values.

Is it possible to do it in awk? Can someone show me an example of it.

```
     Eg input file: 1, 4, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9, 2, 4
     output: 
        below 2: 20%
        below 4: 40%
        below 6: 50% 
        below 8: 90%
```

** included below or equal

Comment: Yes. Post a [mcve] including concise, testable sample input and expected output and we can get started helping you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming data is in `a.txt` file:

```
awk -v limit=16 '$1 < limit {count++} END {print 100*count/NR}' a.txt
```

Where `limit` is the cutoff value, it just counts the elements smaller than limit (`$1 < limit`), and after all lines are read it prints the count divided by number of records (`NR`).

Comment: Never use all upper case for variable names as it can clash with builtin names and as written you'd get a divide by zero error for an empty file.

Comment: Corrected the limit, but as for empty file, it is an error case, because what should be written 100 or 0?

Comment: @krzyk the OP would have to tell you their requirement for handling an empty file (nothing, NaN, zero, something else?), it just won't be "divide by zero error" or similar.